# DataSet relation with multiple joins in query

Tags: c#, dataset, relation

I'm filling dataset from multiple tables using relation on this way:

```
private void UcitajZahtjeve()
    {
        string query1 = "SELECT tblrezgo.IDRadnik, CONCAT(tblradnik.Ime, ' ', tblradnik.Prezime) AS ImePrezime, tblrezgo.EmailRadnik, tblrezgo.creationTime, tblrezgo.IDUnos ";
        query1 += "FROM tblrezgo ";
        query1 += "LEFT JOIN tblradnik ON tblradnik.IDRadnik = tblrezgo.IDRadnik ";
        query1 += "LEFT JOIN tblrezgolog ON tblrezgolog.IDUnos = tblrezgo.IDUnos ";
        query1 += "WHERE (tblrezgolog.OdobrenoN=1 AND tblrezgolog.OdobrenoHR=1) ";
        query1 += "ORDER BY tblrezgo.creationTime ASC";

        string query2 = "SELECT IDUnos, DatumGO, OdobrenoN, OdobrenoHR FROM tblrezgolog";

        gridZahtjevi.DataSource = dbTwoTableRelation(query1, query2, "Detalji", "IDUnos", "IDUnos").Tables[0];
        gridZahtjevi.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("Detalji", gridDetails);
    }

private DataSet dbTwoTableRelation(string query1, string query2, string relationName, string fieldName1, string fieldName2)
        {
        MySqlDataAdapter table1;
        MySqlDataAdapter table2;

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        table1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, this.connection);
        table2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, this.connection);

        table1.Fill(myDataSet, "mainList");
        table2.Fill(myDataSet, "subList");

        myDataSet.Relations.Add(relationName, myDataSet.Tables["mainList"].Columns[fieldName1], myDataSet.Tables["subList"].Columns[fieldName2]).Nested = true;

      return myDataSet;

    }
```

The queries work fine but if I run this code I get error even application is loaded grid is empty.

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.Data.dll

If I remove from query1 one join clause then everthing is ok. 
I don't understand what causes problem, whay two joins are problem?!

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch the constructed query1 at runtime and try to execute in your database,
Then it will be easy to findout the error

Comment: I've already do that. Query works fine. I think that problem is in method DataSet dbTwoTableRelation() on line myDataSet.Relations.Add(relationName, myDataSet.Tables["mainList"].Columns[fieldName1], myDataSet.Tables["subList"].Columns[fieldName2]).Nested = true;

But I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Use Query Like this. It should work.

---

```
     string query1 = "SELECT tblrezgo.IDRadnik, CONCAT(tblradnik.Ime, ' ',   
                     tblradnik.Prezime) AS ImePrezime, tblrezgo.EmailRadnik, 
                     tblrezgo.creationTime, tblrezgo.IDUnos ";
                     query1 += "FROM tblrezgo ";
                     query1 += "LEFT JOIN tblradnik ON tblradnik.IDRadnik =  
                     tblrezgo.IDRadnik , tblrezgo  ";
                     query1 += "LEFT JOIN tblrezgolog ON tblrezgolog.IDUnos =  
                     tblrezgo.IDUnos ";
                     query1 += "WHERE (tblrezgolog.OdobrenoN=1 AND 
                     tblrezgolog.OdobrenoHR=1) ";
                     query1 += "ORDER BY tblrezgo.creationTime ASC";
```

Comment: There is error like Not unique table/alias: 'tblrezgo'